# Non-object on this code

Tags: php, pdo

```
    private $dbhost = "localhost";
    private $dbname = "bootfor";
    private $dbuser = "root";
    private $dbpass = "";
    private $dbh;
    public $row;

function __costruct()
        {
            try {
                $this->dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->dbhost;charset=utf8;dbname=$this->dbname", $this->dbuser, $this->dbpass);
                $this->dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
                $this->dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            }

            catch(PDOException $error) {
                print "<br > Error!: " . $error->getMessage() . "<br />";
            }
        }

        public

        function categories()
        {
            $this->dbh->prepare("select categories");
            $this->dbh->execute();
            $this->row = $this->dbh->fetch();
        }
```

Error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in F:\index.php on line 35

I am probably being stupid but, any ideas as to why this is a non-object? I've tried looking at it a few hundred times but I can't figure it out, I've fixed this issue before I just can't remember how...

Comment: In the grand scheme, it's a good thing the connection failed, since your query is totally incorrect anyways.

Answer (score 3):

You mispelled `__costruct()` where it should be `__construct()`